# Windows 10 Storage Spaces out of space with 2TB free space

Tags: windows, storage, storage-spaces

I'm using 5 3TB drives to set up a Storage Space pool with parity, as each disk contributes 2.72TB to the pool, I have a total of 9.07TB (2.72x4). However, even though the disk "Properties" shows I still have 1.92TB of free space, Storage Spaces manager reports every disk is now at full capacity, and I can't copy larger files to the pool anymore. I'm cheated out of almost 2TB! Someone please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

9.07TB is not 2.72TB x4. There's some inconsistency there.

If you made something like the equivalent of RAID 5, you should have 10.88TB of space.

Looks like this is almost the difference you report.

Storage space is a big mess, why use it in the first place ?
To understand the actual probable mess, check this [documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/LRC12-cheng20webpage.pdf).

What you could do is check if there are no hidden/junk data somewhere with an utility like DiskSpace. There may be stuff reported as deleted but not actually deleted/removed.

Given your case you should of made a classic RAID 5, or a RAID 0 out of 4 drives to have super-speed and use the 5th as a kind of manual backup for the critical part of your data.

Comment: 1. My mistake, 9.07TB is actually the total disk space I've used, I should indeed have 10.88TB total.

Comment: 2. Hardware-wise, all I have is a basic 5 drive enclosure, so my only solution is some kind of software RAID, this is why I chose Storage Space.

Comment: Should be the equivalent of a RAID 5 then, so check for hidden junk files. Run a windows junk decontaminator to get rid of all the hidden junk that is being reported as free space. You should notice some difference.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know maybe I can add some more insight, also having the issue, free space is vanishing. I have not been able to adequately isolate the root cause. I thought perhaps `Google Chrome` was causing it, so I tweaked some settings to prevent unnecessarily caching certain bits of data, sharing data with `Google`, so on and so forth. Helped some, but still the issue persists.

I also ran `WinDirStat` on my C:, and actually it seems like in the represented files, there are only 478GB out of a 2TB drive accounted for. So I wonder, is it perhaps a registry issue? Windows is perhaps creating snapshots? I have not looked into this aspect yet.

I relocated some apps to another drive in an emergency response to the free space vanishing to near ZERO available.

I do have some *updates* pending which I have been postponing for some time now, so I wonder if there is a registry snapshot or something of that nature taking place that I can dial back by several orders of magnitude and reclaim my drive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Following up, there is an `UNKNOWN` whatever that is occupying 1.3TB out of the available 1.8somethingTB, which jives with the free space report in Properties, but what the heck is that anyway?

Comment: "Me too!" is nowhere close to an answer.  In SU, an answer means that you are providing a solution to the problem.  This is not a solution to the problem.